# Laravel formatting JSON output

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Is there a simple way to return more objects with different attribute name in JSON response?

For example I have a `User` model which has attributes `name, password, xy` and if I do `return User::all();` I will return all users. But what if I want to return a list of custom objects where I will return JSON format like:

```
{
    'username' : ...
    'pass': ...
    'xyz' : ...
    'from_related_model' : ...
}
```

so I will have name of fields returned differently then they are in DB, and also attach to each returned object an attribute from related model.

I don't want to use mutators as I only want to return like that within one controller. I know I can traverse through object with foreach and make a new object by assigning values, and returning merged object. But is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Yes. Would you be able to add an example of how you would do it with a foreach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to generate the list of objects to return manually.

**Example:** if you wanted to return a custom object for each user fetched from the database you could do something like the following in your controller:

```
$result = [];
foreach (User::all() as $user) {
  $result[] = [
    'username' => $user->username,
    'full_name' => $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name,
    'xyz' => 5,
  ];
}

return $result;
```

Every time you return an array or a **Collection** from controller method, it will be converted automatically to JSON.